# rvm installed and not found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rvm

installed rvm this way on debian server:

```
root@aaa-env1-chef-demo-dal01:/home/partuck# curl -L https://get.rvm.io | bash -s stable
  % Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100   184  100   184    0     0   1149      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:--  1628
100 22721  100 22721    0     0  84938      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 84938
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/archive/1.26.11.tar.gz
Downloading https://github.com/rvm/rvm/releases/download/1.26.11/1.26.11.tar.gz.asc
gpg: Signature made Mon Mar 30 21:52:13 2015 UTC using RSA key ID BF04FF17
gpg: Good signature from "Michal Papis (RVM signing) <mpapis@gmail.com>"
gpg: WARNING: This key is not certified with a trusted signature!
gpg:          There is no indication that the signature belongs to the owner.
Primary key fingerprint: 409B 6B17 96C2 7546 2A17  0311 3804 BB82 D39D C0E3
     Subkey fingerprint: 62C9 E5F4 DA30 0D94 AC36  166B E206 C29F BF04 FF17
GPG verified '/usr/local/rvm/archives/rvm-1.26.11.tgz'

Upgrading the RVM installation in /usr/local/rvm/
Upgrade of RVM in /usr/local/rvm/ is complete.

# partuck,
#
#   Thank you for using RVM!
#   We sincerely hope that RVM helps to make your life easier and more enjoyable!!!
#
# ~Wayne, Michal & team.

 In case of problems: http://rvm.io/help and https://twitter.com/rvm_io

Upgrade Notes:

  * No new notes to display.

root@aaa-env1-chef-demo-dal01:/home/partuck# rvm list
bash: rvm: command not found
```

As you can see the rvm is still not avaiable. there is no `~/.rvm` directory to source `(~/.source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm)`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Looks like you install rvm on a [`system-wide`](https://rvm.io/rvm/install#2-load-rvm-into-your-shell-sessions-as-a-function), run command:

```
$ source /etc/profile.d/rvm.sh
```

and check again:

```
$ rvm -v
```

or restart shell. thx [`@Gearmode`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34481648/rvm-installed-and-not-found/34481748#comment56705246_34481748)

Answer (score 2):

You could fix this issue by writing

```
source ~/.rvm/scripts/rvm
```

in `.bashrc` file.